# ASP.NET Core client side validation for custom validation attribute on razor page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

Currently, this is what my model class looks like, with the custom validation attribute

**Client.cs**

```
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Bookkeeping")]
    public bool Bookkeeping { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Personal Income Taxation")]
    public bool Personal_Income_Taxation { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Self-Employed Business Taxes")]
    public bool Self_Employed_Business_Taxes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("GST/PST/WCB Returns")]
    public bool GST_PST_WCB_Returns { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Tax Returns")]
    public bool Tax_Returns { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Payroll Services")]
    public bool Payroll_Services { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Previous Year Filings")]
    public bool Previous_Year_Filings { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Govt. Requisite Form Applicaitons")]
    public bool Government_Requisite_Form_Applications { get; set; }

    [StringLength(220, ErrorMessage = "Cannot exceed more than 220 characters")]
    public string Other { get; set; }

    [CheckboxAndOtherValidation(nameof(Bookkeeping),
nameof(Personal_Income_Taxation),
nameof(Self_Employed_Business_Taxes),
nameof(GST_PST_WCB_Returns),
nameof(Tax_Returns),
nameof(Payroll_Services),
nameof(Previous_Year_Filings),
nameof(Government_Requisite_Form_Applications), ErrorMessage = "At least one of the checkboxes or the 'Other' field must be filled")]
    public bool AreCheckboxesAndOtherValid { get; set; }
```

**CheckboxAndOtherValidation.cs**

```
public class CheckboxAndOtherValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    readonly object TRUE = true;
    string[] _alltheOtherProperty;

    public CheckboxAndOtherValidation(params string[] alltheOthersProperty)
    {
        _alltheOtherProperty = alltheOthersProperty;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage((validationContext.DisplayName));

        bool IsOtherNull = false;
        bool IsAnyCheckboxChecked = false;

        if (_alltheOtherProperty?.Count() > 0 != true)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
        }

        var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(nameof(Client.Other));
        if (otherPropertyInfo != null)
        {
            object otherPropertyValue = otherPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            if (otherPropertyValue == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(otherPropertyValue.ToString()))
            {
                IsOtherNull = true;
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < _alltheOtherProperty.Length; ++i)
        {
            var prop = _alltheOtherProperty[i];
            var propertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(prop);
            if (propertyInfo == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            object propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            if (Equals(TRUE, propertyValue))
            {
                IsAnyCheckboxChecked = true;
            }
        }

        if (IsOtherNull && !IsAnyCheckboxChecked)
            return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
        else
            return ValidationResult.Success;

    }
}
```

I want to be able to have client side validation when submitting a form. All other fields of my form work from the client side except the custom validation that I have, by doing something like this

```html
<span class="text-danger col-3" asp-validation-for="Client.Name"></span>
```

How can I get the custom validation attribute to work the same way? (Note: client side scripting works when I include a file in my razor page called "ValidationScriptsPartial", in which there are references to multiple jquery files. I believe thats how client side validation is happening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the custom validation attribute to work the same way?

If you'd like to do same validation logic on client side as you did on custom server-side validation attribute on model property.

You can try to implement custom client-side validation based on your actual requirement, for more information, please refer to this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-client-side-validation

Besides, if possible, you can try to use the [[Remote] attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#remote-attribute) that also enables us to validate combinations of fields, which might help you achieve same requirement easily.