# Stop form on Razor page from submitting if an input value = "XXX"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a form on an ASP.Net Razor page which I want to prevent from posting if the value of an input box equals a certain value. The form part looks like this.

```html
<td><label asp-for="Item.FromLocation" class="control-label"></label></td>
<td>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Item.FromLocation" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Item.FromLocation" class="text-danger"></span>
</td>
```

This is my `OnPost` in the page model

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(ItemModel item)
{
    ValidLocation = await LocationModel.CreateAsync(item.FromLocation);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    if (ValidLocation.Location == "XXX")
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("FROMLOCATION", "Invalid Location");
        return Page();
    }
    else
    {
        if (await item.InsertAsync() == true)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("Add", new { Item.EntryDate, Item.Initials });
        }
        else
            return RedirectToPage("Error");
    }
}
```

The database will return a XXX when it doesn't find a matching value and when the page is run, I do go into the `ModelState.AddModel` section but it still continues to carry out the post, which returns an error.

How do I show the error right on the page (and stop it from posting) in the same way I do when the Required fields are left blank?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core client side validation for custom validation attribute on razor page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62163389/asp-net-core-client-side-validation-for-custom-validation-attribute-on-razor-pag)

Comment: I am not sure. If what I am trying to do can only be done on the client, then maybe it does. I think my issue has something to with the fact that I am trying to do it on the OnPost and by this time the client validation is already validated so the page goes through the submit anyway. I now think I am going to have come at this a different way then how I intended.

Comment: The xxx is based on the database or it's a static value? If this is based on the database and you want to do it at client side, you should use ajax to call the server method to return the value and do the validation in the client side.

Comment: Look at remote validation: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/validation/remote-validation

Comment: Remote Validation is what I am looking for. So, I am trying to use that example in my code right now. I will probably need to start another Question because I am having trouble with the PageHandler. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Just remember that client side validation isn't security, a malicious user can always post what they want.